# Optimal way to chain Promise.all() with many calls many times

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm developing a chain of API calls that work by making calls to an api with an array of id's, getting a return of data, and making the next call to a different endpoint with some data retrieved.

Now this is totally the naïve solution - i'm hoping to get some input into how to best optimise this. I may have some 500 data points to go through in each of these.

What returns from `apiHelper.apiCall(data, endpoint)` is an array of promises that are resolved and managed in the `Promise.all();` each time - meaning

Currently it looks something like 6 nested Promise.all() inside each others .then():

```
Promise.all(function(){})
.then(function(){
    Promise.all(function(){})
    .then(function(){
        Promise.all(function(){})
        .then(function(){
            Promise.all(function(){})
            .then(function(){
            ...and so on...
            });
        });
    });
});
```

ie in semi real code.

```
 var datapoints = req.body.toString().split("\n");
    var startingCount = datapoints.length;

    var preFailed = [];

    //initial naïve solution with nested Promise.all();
    var promises = apiHelper.apiCall(datapoints, endpoint + '?referenceId=');
    console.log('#INITIAL COUNT', promises.length);
    Promise
        .all(promises)
        .then(function (orderItems) {
            var itemHrefs = [];
            orderItems.forEach(function (oi) {
                if (oi.data.items && oi.data.items.length > 0) {
                    itemHrefs.push(oi.data.items[0].href); //get item href (has full order ref)
                }
            })

            //Find order items
            promises = apiHelper.apiCall(itemHrefs, '');
            Promise
                .all(promises)
                .then(function (retrievedOrders) {
                    var consumerOrderHrefs = [];
                    retrievedOrders.forEach(function (ro) {
                        if (ro.data.consumers) {
                            consumerOrderHrefs.push(ro.data.consumers.href); //get item href (has full order ref)
                        }
                    })


                    promises = apiHelper.apiCall(consumerOrderHrefs, '');
                    console.log('#STEP 3 FIND CONSUMERORDER COUNT', promises.length);
                    Promise
                        .all(promises)
                        .then(function (retrievedConsumers) {
                            var consumerHrefs = [];
                            retrievedConsumers.forEach(function (c) {
                                if (c.data.items[0]) {
                                    consumerHrefs.push(c.data.items[0].href); //get item href (has full order ref)
                                }
                            })

                            promises = apiHelper.apiCall(consumerHrefs, '');
                            console.log('#STEP 4 FIND CONSUMER COUNT', promises.length);
                            Promise
                                .all(promises)
                                .then(function (consumer) {
                                    var guestHrefs = [];
                                    consumer.forEach(function (c) {
                                        if (c.data.guest.href) {
                                            guestHrefs.push(c.data.guest.href); //get item href (has full order ref)
                                        }
                                    })

                                    promises = apiHelper.apiCall(guestHrefs, '');
                                    console.log('#STEP 5 GUEST COUNT', promises.length);
                                    Promise
                                        .all(promises)
                                        .then(function (guests) {
                                            var guest = [];
                                            guests.forEach(function (g) {
                                                if (g.data) {
                                                    guest.push(g.data); //get item href (has full order ref)
                                                }
                                            })
                                            res.status(200).json({guest});
                                        })
                                        .catch(function (err) {
                                            console.log('#ERR', err);
                                            res.status(500).send(err);
                                        });


                                })
                                .catch(function (err) {
                                    console.log('#ERR', err);
                                    res.status(500).send(err);
                                });
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.log('#ERR', err);
                            res.status(500).send(err);
                        });
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('#ERR', err);
                    res.status(500).send(err);
                });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('#ERR', err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle you should apply here is the same as you would for any other promises - return a promise within a `then` and handle its result in the next `then`:

```
Promise.all(apiCall()) 
    .then(function (results) {
         var nextItems = // do something with results 

         return Promise.all(apiHelper.apiCall(nextItems, ''));
    })
    .then(function (results) {
         var nextItems = // do something with results 

         return Promise.all(apiHelper.apiCall(nextItems, ''));
    })
    .then(function (results) {
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: Ah so chaining `.then()` works if what is returned in the previous is a set of promises. How smart

Comment: @mewc Promise.all doesn't return a set of promises. It returns a single Promise.

Comment: Even better. Can confirm this works. Thanks JLRishe

Answer (score 3):

Look into [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
const allPromises = async () => {
    await Promise.all(...);
    await Promise.all(...);
    //Etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
var promise = Promise.all(...);
promise = promise.then(() => Promise.all(...))
promise = promise.then(() => Promise.all(...))
promise = promise.then(() => Promise.all(...))
promise = promise.then(() => Promise.all(...))
promise.then(() => {
  console.log('all done!')
})
```

Comment: While a good solution, chaining `.then().then().then()` is much more elegant (from JLRishe https://stackoverflow.com/a/55370441/5281187)